# Find last array element for every property type in document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with mongodb query. I have schema like this:

```
{
  type: TYPE_1,
  amount: 10
  list: [
    { ...}
  ]
}

{
   type: TYPE_1,
   amount: 14
   list: [
     { ...}
   ]
}

{
   type: TYPE_2,
   amount: 17
   list: [
     { ...}
   ]
}

...
```

I want to filter documents with biggest **amount** value for every **type** field.
Like this:

```
{
   type: TYPE_1,
   amount: 14
   list: [
     { ...}
   ]
}

{
   type: TYPE_2,
   amount: 17
   list: [
     { ...}
   ]
}
```

Is it possible using mongodb aggregations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: 
    {
      "_id": "$type", 
      "amount": {$max: "$amount"}
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I need to have list property in next stage for max amount value as in my example

Comment: you can add it using "list": {$first: "$list"}

Comment: this solution works but i needed to use $last instead of $first and list must be sorted, but in my case list is already sorted so this is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with `$group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type", //group by type
      "amount": { //get the maximum
        $max: "$amount"
      },
      data: {
        $push: { //add list so that you can use it in the next stage
          "lists": "$list"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NcqX7crarPQ)